# Functions - Sets of inputs/outputs - Validate the claims

Tags: real-analysis

I am solving some problems from the "Problems in real analysis" by aliprantis et. el. (it is available in the pdf format on Google).

I am looking at the first chaper's problems in elementary set theory. Problems 1.1, problems: 7) and 9). I have two questions. ***First one*** (relating to 7):

The problem (to validate the claim):

$$f \left(\bigcap_{i \in I} A_i \right) \subseteq \bigcap_{i \in I} f(A_i)$$

Would there ever be a case where the set on the left is a subset of the set on the right. Because I can only think of the cases when the two are equal. So I would rather state the problem as, validate:

$$f \left(\bigcap_{i \in I} A_i \right) = \bigcap_{i \in I} f(A_i)$$

***Second question*** (relating to problem 9):
Why do we now have the equals sign instead of the subset or equals sign:

$$f^{-1} \left(\bigcap_{i \in I} B_i \right) = \bigcap_{i \in I} f(B_i)$$

and I would prove this second case in the exacttly same way I have proved the first one, which is:

$$f^{-1} \left(\bigcap_{i \in I} B_i \right) \subseteq f(B_j) \ \ \text{for some $j \in I$} \iff  f^{-1} \left(\bigcap_{i \in I} B_i \right) \subseteq \bigcap_{i \in I} f(B_i)$$

***Would this be incorrect?*** **(I guess I have three questions then).**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x^2$. Then $f([0,1]\cap [-1,0])\ne f([0,1])\cap([-1,0])$.